# OpenCV + Linux + badly supported camera = wrong pixel format

Tags: opencv, webcam

I'm trying to grab frames from a web cam using OpenCV. I also tried 'cheese'. Both give me a pretty weird picture: distorted, wrong colors. Using mplayer I was able to figure out the correct codec "yuy2". Even mplayer sometimes would select the wrong codec ("yuv"), which makes it look just like using OpenCV / cheese to capture an image.

Can I somehow tell OpenCV which codec to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the latest version of opencv you can set the capture format form the camera with the same fourcc style code you would use for video.  See http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture

it may still take a bit of trial-and-error, terms like YUV, YUYV, YUY2 are used a bit loosely by the camera maker, the driver maker, the operating system, the directshow layer and opencv !

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV automatically selects the first available capture backend [(see here)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html). It can be that it is not using V4L2 automatically.

Also set both `-D WITH_V4L=ON` and `-D WITH_LIBV4L=ON` if building from source.

In order to set the pixel format to be used set the `CAP_PROP_FOURCC` property of the capture:

```
  capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.cam_id, cv2.CAP_V4L2)
  scapture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'))
  width = 1920
  height = 1080
  capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
  capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
```